# How to create unique random numbers from a given Random generator

Tags: java, random, numbers, unique

```
Write an efficient algorithm to print the following two outputs
```

> You are given a pre-defined function named getrand100() which returns
>   an integer which is one random number from 1-100. You can call this
>   function as many times as you want but beware that this function is
>   quite resource intensive. You cannot use any other random generator.
>   You canNOT change the definition of getrand100().

```
int getrand100(){
    Random rand = new Random();
return (1+rand.nextInt(100));      
}
```

- Output1: Print numbers 1-20 in random order. (Not 20 random numbers)
- Output2: Print numbers 1-200 in random order. (Not 200 random numbers)

Note:

- i.   Every number should be printed exactly once.
- ii.  There should be no pattern in the numbers listing. List should be completely random
  i.e., all numbers have equal probability appearing at any place.
- iii. You may call getrand100() any number of time to get randomnumber
  from 1 to 100.
- iv.  You cannot use any other random generator
  function except getrand100().

Comment: Probably the most simple solution you can start with is the `brute-force` solution :). Add to a list a number while it is not there yet - but this is not "efficient".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use the Random generator given to compute the required random numbers.

1) For random numbers 1-20, just divide the 100 numbers equally to represent 1 to 20.

2) To generate 1-200, find the even numbers from 1 to 200 and then add (-1 or 0) to it to get all the numbers from 1 to 200.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Rand20_200{
   int number20[]=new int[20]; //numbers in random order
   int number200[]=new int[200];

   public Rand20_200(){
    int n=0;
    int ngen[]=new int[20]; //to store which random numbers are generated
    while(n<20){
      int rnd=1 + (getrand100()-1) / 5;
      if (ngen[rnd-1]==0){
        ngen[rnd-1]=1;
        number20[n++]=rnd;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Random 20 numbers");
    print(number20);

    ngen=new int[200]; //to store which random numbers are generated
    int numoff[]={-1,0}; //offset to add
    n=0;
    while(n<200){
      int rnd=numoff[(getrand100()-1)/50]+ (getrand100()*2);
      if (ngen[rnd-1]==0){
     ngen[rnd-1]=1;
     number200[n++]=rnd;
      }
    }   
    System.out.println("\nRandom 200 numbers");
    print(number200);
   }

   int getrand100(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    return (1+rand.nextInt(100));      
   }

   void print(int arr[]){
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
     }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
     new Rand20_200();
   }

 }
```

Comment: That's not the kind of information that would help the OP to solve the **homework** by himself.

Comment: what do you mean and what is your problem? If you don't have any constructive suggestion to my solution, then you don't have to comment.

Comment: @Subs Homeworks shouldn't be answered in detail ,well +1 for the input

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is homework, I'll keep the answer terse. :)

Look into the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator %

Comment: Yes, this is a home work but i am unable to implement some logic for this. Please help me guys its urgent. thanks.

Comment: As already mentioned, the brute force solution may be the easiest to implement if you're crunched for time.

Comment: @dcrooney - normally I'd agree with you, however the instructor makes it clear that getrand100() is "quite resource intensive" suggesting that any calls over the bare minimum will incur a grading penalty.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list with your value (1 - 20, 1 - 200) and a random number, then sort the list on the random number.

```
public class RandomListItem
{
    int value;
    int sortindex;

    public RandomListItem(x,y)
    {
        value = x;
        sortindex = y;
    }
}

for(int i = 1; i <= maxvalue; i++)
{
    list.add(new RandomListItem(i, getrand100());
}
```

This might not be so good for the 200 list, since you can only generate random numbers up to 100.  Might want to use getrand100() * getrand100() or something to generate a wider range of random numbers.